# Query to display newest post in shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to write a query that will display my blog's newest post, to then call as a shortcode, but I'm running into some syntax errors.

Code:

```
function newest_post_query() {
    $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=1' );
    while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post();
    echo '<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>';
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
add_shortcode('newest_post', 'newest_post_query');
```

I'll edit the output markup once I get the query working. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: What are the syntax errors?

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/ourcore/public_html/wp-content/themes/portfolio/functions.php on line 108` (which is line 5 in the snippet). Other than that, I'm not sure if the query will work.

Comment: That error is unrelated to the query, what is line 108 of functions.php?

Comment: No, I mentioned that line 108 in functions.php is line 5 in the snippet above. When I remove the query, there's no error.

Comment: you are missing endwhile on line 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start a `while` statement, but never end it. You also have some syntax issues in your link tag. Finally, `WP_Query` takes an array of arguments, not a string:

```
function newest_post_query() {
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page' => 1,) );
    while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post();
        echo '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a>';
    endwhile;  // This was missing
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
add_shortcode('newest_post', 'newest_post_query');
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. I noticed the while loop was open after I posted it here. This works as expected, but the echoed content isn't being inserted where I'm calling the shortcode in my page. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: It was because the newest post content needed to be returned, not echoed. Updated and worked. Thanks again!